# When are time-varying vectors $\phi_1(t), \phi_2(t) \text{for } t \in \mathbb{R}$ linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra

Specifically, consider the example when $\phi_1(t) = \begin{bmatrix}0\\t\end{bmatrix}$, $\phi_2(t) = \begin{bmatrix}0\\t^2\end{bmatrix} \text{for} \ \ t \in \mathbb{R}$ are two time-varying vectors(with the underlying field being $\mathbb{R}$). Now for linear independence, we need that for $\alpha_1, \alpha_2 \in \mathbb{R}, \ \alpha_1\phi_1(t) + \alpha_2\phi_2(t) = \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix} \implies \alpha_1 = \alpha_2 = 0 \ \ \forall \  t$.
I tried to prove linear independence by contradiction. I started by assuming that they are linearly dependent which means $\exists \ \alpha_1, \alpha_2$ not all equal to zero such that $\alpha_1\phi_1(t) + \alpha_2\phi_2(t) = \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}$
and I took 3 cases:
(a)$\alpha_1 \neq 0, \alpha_2 = 0$ ;
(b)$\alpha_2 \neq 0, \alpha_1 = 0$ ;
(c)$\alpha_1 \neq 0, \alpha_2 \neq 0$;
In cases (a) and (b), the contradiction is straightforward but case (c) is where I'm a little confused. Here, I am getting $\alpha_1 = -t\alpha_2 \ \forall \ t$ which seems to indicate that $\alpha_1 \text{ depends on } \alpha_2$ through $t$. But, intuitively, I know that the dependence must be through a constant and not $t$. How do I formalize this argument to conclude that this is only possible if $\alpha_1 = 0 \text{ and } \alpha_2 = 0$(thereby contradicting the assumption of case (c) and proving that $\phi_1(t), \phi(t)$ are linearly independent)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\alpha_{1}t+\alpha_{2}t^{2}=0$, $\forall t \in \mathbb{R}$ when $t=1$ we have:
$\alpha_{1}+\alpha_{2}=0$, so $\alpha_{2}=-\alpha_{1}$.
Then we have that $\alpha_{1}t-\alpha_{1}t^{2}=0$, $\forall t \in \mathbb{R}$.
So when $t=2$ we have that:
$2\alpha_{1}-4\alpha_{1}=0$, so $-2\alpha_{1}=0$, so $\alpha_{1}=0$, and in consecuence, $\alpha_{2}=0$.

Comment: thanks for helping me with that. I can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

You require that $\alpha_1 \phi_1(t) + \alpha_2 \phi(t) =0$ implies $\alpha_1 = \alpha_2 = 0$ for all $t$ and you have shown that if $\alpha_1 \neq 0 \neq \alpha_2$ then $\alpha_1 \phi_1(t) + \alpha_2 \phi(t) =0$ implies $\alpha_1 = -t \alpha_2$, so the definition of dependence you gave is satisfied.

To understand why this makes sense intuitively consider the geometric interpretation of linear (in)dependence. A (finite) set of vectors is linearly dependent if the number of vectors is larger than the number of dimensions they span. In particular, in the case of just two vectors dependence means that they lie on the same line. In other words one is a multiple of the other. In the example you provided that is clearly the case, both the vectors point in the same direction for all times $t>0$. However, their magnitudes grow at different rates, so one cannot be a constant multiple of the other. (It is however a scalar multiple).

I think you might be confused because the term "constant" is sometimes used in places where "scalar" would be more accurate. Linear dependence is  such a case.

Comment: thanks for the nice explanation and for clearing the confusion with the constant term. This is an equally good answer, but I can only mark one as the accepted answer.